# unable to resolve IP in reverse DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns

This question itself has been asked before several times, but none of the answers given there has worked for me so far. So probably I'm doing something wrong, and I can't figure out what.

I'm running a domain (example.org at IP 81.4.126.199) and I would like to properly configure the reverse DNS entries. When doing a dig for example.org, I get `126.4.81.in-addr.arpa.   1789    IN  SOA dns1.ramnode.com. nick.ramnode.com. 2013121911 28800 7200 604800 86400`.

So, naturally (as I found all over the internet), I added a PTR record pointing `mail.example.org` to `example.org`. This has been far over 24 hours and doing a reverse DNS lookup on my IP still results in an "unable to resolve". Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That isn't what PTR records are for.

You must add a PTR record somewhere in the DNS:

```
199.126.4.81.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR mail.webhozt.eu.
```

It looks, from the SOA record you posted, that this is something you will have to work with ramnode on, as the server that hosts the record is dns1.ramzone.com.

The rDNS is a separate hierarchy from the forward DNS (kind of... they're still both rooted at `.`) and you can't put your rDNS data in your forward DNS zones.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Yes, I had to arrange it with my VPS provider, there was even a little field for it in my VPS control panel! Now it resolves flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

The PTR record doesn't get created in your DNS zone, it gets created in the rDNS zone that encompasses that ip address. You need to speak with the party that allocated that ip address to you and ask them to create the PTR record in that zone for you.